# Calculation of number and percentage of right answers for each participant in R

Tags: r, loops, calculation, survey

I have a table of survey with answers that might be "right" or "wrong":

| Participant | Answer 1 | Answer 2 | Answer 3 | ... | Answer n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Right | Wrong | Wrong | ... | Right |
| 2 | Right | Wrong | Right | .... | Right |
| 3 | Wrong | Right | Right | ... | Wrong |

I want to calculate the number and percentage of "right" questions for every participant and make result that will look like this:

| Participant | Number of right answers | Percentage of right answers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | p1 | p1, % |
| 2 | p2 | p2, % |
| 3 | p3 | p3, % |
| ... | ... | .... |
| n | pn | pn, % |

I think it is possible to do through loop, however, I don' know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rowSums` and `rowMeans` from `base R`. Since you don't provide a reproducible example, I created one, with 10 questions and participants:

```r
df <- data.frame(participant = 1:10, 
           as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c("Right", "Wrong"), 100, replace = TRUE), nrow = 10)))

#    participant    V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10
# 1            1 Right Right Right Wrong Wrong Right Wrong Wrong Wrong Right
# 2            2 Wrong Right Right Right Wrong Right Wrong Wrong Right Right
# 3            3 Right Right Wrong Right Right Wrong Right Wrong Right Right
# 4            4 Right Wrong Right Right Right Right Right Right Wrong Wrong
# 5            5 Right Right Right Wrong Right Right Wrong Right Wrong Wrong
# 6            6 Wrong Wrong Right Wrong Wrong Wrong Wrong Wrong Wrong Right
# 7            7 Wrong Right Wrong Wrong Right Right Wrong Wrong Wrong Wrong
# 8            8 Right Wrong Wrong Right Right Wrong Wrong Right Right Wrong
# 9            9 Right Wrong Wrong Right Right Right Wrong Wrong Right Right
# 10          10 Wrong Wrong Wrong Wrong Wrong Wrong Right Wrong Wrong Right

data.frame(df[1],
           right_answers = rowSums(df[-1] == "Right"),
           p_right_answers = rowMeans(df[-1] == "Right"))

#    participant right_answers p_right_answers
# 1            1             5             0.5
# 2            2             6             0.6
# 3            3             7             0.7
# 4            4             7             0.7
# 5            5             6             0.6
# 6            6             2             0.2
# 7            7             3             0.3
# 8            8             5             0.5
# 9            9             6             0.6
# 10          10             2             0.2
```